# system wordpress/drupal confusion

Tags: drupal, installation, mamp

I'm a newbie.  Attempting to install local MAMP Drupal CiviCRM - following the wiki steps.  When I get to the CiviCRM install script, it throws the following error - for some reason the install script seems to think I'm running WordPress.

I've purged it all, tried a again from scratch.  Same issue.

=========================
Notice: Use of undefined constant WP_PLUGIN_DIR - assumed 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 63

Notice: Use of undefined constant WP_PLUGIN_DIR - assumed 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 64

Notice: Use of undefined constant WP_PLUGIN_URL - assumed 'WP_PLUGIN_URL' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 65

Warning: require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR/civicrm/civicrm//CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 75

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR/civicrm/civicrm//CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 75

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the tarball for drupal?

Comment: Yes, I triple checked.  It's the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't experienced this myself, but -- skimming the code in `index.php` -- it appears to track a variable called `civicrm_install_type`. The variable defaults to `drupal` but can be set to `wordpress` by passing `?civicrm_install_type=wordpress`. Once it is set, it's stored in the `SESSION` and reused for future page-views.

One way you could probably trigger this behavior is to install WordPress+CiviCRM, swap out the code base, and replace it with a Drupal+CiviCRM codebase (on the same server, using the same browser session).

If this were the situation, you could get around it by either:

- Resetting the PHP session (eg deleting cookies or logging out).
- Explicitly passing `?civicrm_install_type=drupal` when visiting `civicrm/install/index.php`.

Comment: I just needed to clear the session and my cookies, and bada bing.  All better.